# Visual Studio Cloud Testing: Deleting uwanted load tests

Tags: visual-studio, testing, load-testing

During the evaluation of Microsofts Cloud load testing I created some test load tests. However I can't seem to find a way to delete these.

I have tried online and in Load Test Manager in Visual Studio, however although visible there does not appear to be a way to delete them.

Comment: Delete them from where? Delete the load tests or their results?

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio team services doesn't seem to have developed this ability yet into their tool. Its amazing how they can miss a delete function, but here a link from their dev community.

[Here's the link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/18616/how-to-delete-load-tests.html)